# Store ArrayList<CustomClass> into database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have a Array list of a custom class which contain a bitmap image and a String. I want to store it in database/sharedpreferences when my app will closed and retrieve it when app is created. I already searched on google but it doesn't helped much.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend you storing images directly in database (I assume you are using SQLite). The cursor you get from SQLite is limited to 1MB, so if you image is in a reasonable quality, you will not get all the bytes. The best approach, in my opinion, is storing the PATH to the file in the Database, and then, in code, get that path and create a bitmap from file.

Comment: Thank you for help. Can you tell me which one is better storing in database or through shared Preferences.

Comment: If the image is the same in every device, for every user, shared preferences is ok. If the image is going to change, or if every user will have a different image, i would store it in database.